# Apply the same code to multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

The VBA below works perfectly fine for Worksheet "X". However, the problem is that I want the same code to be applied simultaneously to worksheet "Y" and "Z" (there are other worksheets as well which do not require this code).

Could you please let me know how to change my VBA below so it refers to worksheets "X", "Y" and "Z" instead of only "X"? thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit

'In a regular module sheet
Public RunWhen As Double    'This statement must go at top of all subs and functions


Sub StartBlink()
    Dim cel As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("X")
        Set cel = .Range("G2")
        If cel.Value > .Range("L3").Value Then
            If cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then    ' Red Text
                cel.Font.ColorIndex = 2        ' White Text
                cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Else
                cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3        ' Red Text
                cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
            End If
        Else
            cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3             'Red text
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
        End If
    End With

    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Application.OnTime RunWhen, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", ,  True
End Sub


Sub StopBlink()
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.OnTime RunWhen, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", ,   False
    On Error GoTo 0

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("X")
        .Range("G2").Font.ColorIndex = 3
        .Range("G2").Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
    End With
End Sub


Sub xStopBlink()
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.OnTime RunWhen, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , False
    On Error GoTo 0
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("X").Range("L3").Font.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just loop through each of the three sheets:

```
Sub StartBlink()
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("X", "Y", "Z"))
        With ws
            Set cel = .Range("G2")
            If cel.Value > .Range("L3").Value Then
                If cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then    ' Red Text
                    cel.Font.ColorIndex = 2        ' White Text
                    cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Else
                    cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3        ' Red Text
                    cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
                End If
            Else
                cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3             'Red text
                cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
            End If
        End With

    Next

    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Application.OnTime RunWhen, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", ,  True
End Sub

Sub StopBlink()
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.OnTime RunWhen, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", ,   False
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("X", "Y", "Z"))
        With ws
            .Range("G2").Font.ColorIndex = 3
            .Range("G2").Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

try adding an argument for your subs, like

```
Option Explicit

'In a regular module sheet
Public RunWhen As Double    'This statement must go at top of all subs and functions

Public wsReference As Worksheet

Sub StartBlink(ByVal NewWsName As Worksheet)
    Dim cel As Range
    Set wsReference = NewWsName
    With NewWsName
        Set cel = .Range("G2")
        If cel.Value > .Range("L3").Value Then
            If cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then    ' Red Text
                cel.Font.ColorIndex = 2        ' White Text
                cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Else
                cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3        ' Red Text
                cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
            End If
        Else
            cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3             'Red text
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
        End If
    End With

    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Application.OnTime RunWhen, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , True
End Sub

Sub StopBlink()
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.OnTime RunWhen, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , False
    On Error GoTo 0

    With wsReference
        .Range("G2").Font.ColorIndex = 3
        .Range("G2").Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
    End With
End Sub

Sub xStopBlink()
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.OnTime RunWhen, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , False
    On Error GoTo 0
    wsReference.Range("L3").Font.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

and should be called like

```
startblink thisworkbook.sheets("X")
startblink thisworkbook.sheets("Y")
```

*posting this code without testing*

Comment: Just for my interest: Why do you make use of `ByVal` here?

Comment: @Peh, Sir, a major mistake, it should be ByRef . Thank you for correcting me. But this code still runs some error. trying to fix it as i reply to your comment. :)

Comment: You will get an error when you try to call the `StartBlink` subroutine without parameters (`ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink"`).  Your best bet is to change the `OnTime` calls to call a new sub that calls `StartBlink`.

Answer (score 0):

This can can be modified to check the conditions 1 by 1 in each sheet and then update, but you cannot have multiple scripts running at the same time.

This should work:

```
Option Explicit

'In a regular module sheet
Public RunWhen As Double    'This statement must go at top of all subs and functions


Sub StartBlink()
    Dim cel As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("X")
        Set cel = .Range("G2")
        If cel.Value > .Range("L3").Value Then
            If cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then    ' Red Text
                cel.Font.ColorIndex = 2        ' White Text
                cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Else
                cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3        ' Red Text
                cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
            End If
        Else
            cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3             'Red text
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
        End If
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("y")
        Set cel = .Range("G2")
        If cel.Value > .Range("L3").Value Then
            If cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then    ' Red Text
                cel.Font.ColorIndex = 2        ' White Text
                cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Else
                cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3        ' Red Text
                cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
            End If
        Else
            cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3             'Red text
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
        End If
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("z")
        Set cel = .Range("G2")
        If cel.Value > .Range("L3").Value Then
            If cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then    ' Red Text
                cel.Font.ColorIndex = 2        ' White Text
                cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Else
                cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3        ' Red Text
                cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
            End If
        Else
            cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3             'Red text
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
        End If
    End With







    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Application.OnTime RunWhen, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", ,  True
End Sub


Sub StopBlink()
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.OnTime RunWhen, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", ,   False
    On Error GoTo 0

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("X")
        .Range("G2").Font.ColorIndex = 3
        .Range("G2").Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
    End With
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("y")
        .Range("G2").Font.ColorIndex = 3
        .Range("G2").Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
    End With
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("z")
        .Range("G2").Font.ColorIndex = 3
        .Range("G2").Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
    End With
End Sub


Sub xStopBlink()
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.OnTime RunWhen, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , False
    On Error GoTo 0
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("X").Range("L3").Font.ColorIndex = 3
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("y").Range("L3").Font.ColorIndex = 3
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("z").Range("L3").Font.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

Comment: It is a bad practice to copy code blocks over again. Make use of [additional functions/procedures with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44043726/3219613) to re-use code or [use a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44043919/3219613)!

Comment: Although my code works, I would recommend using YowE3k's it is much cleaner, and doesn't repeat any code, and will also make it easier for you to add other worksheets.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need `Activate` method: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("name").Activate`.

From MSDN:
*Calling this method is equivalent to clicking the sheet's tab.*

Try this:

```
Sub tt()

Dim sheets As Variant, s As Variant
sheets = Array("X", "Y", "Z", ...)

For Each s In sheets
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(s).Activate
    ' call your sub here
Next s

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks but I think it's something with arrays however I can't make it work

Comment: Definitely don't use `Activate`.  It is not needed here, and it just leads to untold numbers of errors in the future.

Comment: I agree, activate wouldn't work. is there  a way to do what I described in my question? thanks

Comment: Don't see any problems with that approach.